# A presentation for $(\Bbb Z/2)^3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

I’m reading the book “Geometric group theory: an introduction”, written by Clara Loh.
In the introduction part there’s the following exercise about presentations of groups (exercise 2.E.24):

**Prove that $$\langle s_1,s_2,s_3 \mid (s_1s_2)^2,(s_1s_3)^2, (s_2s_3)^2\rangle\cong (\Bbb Z/2)^3$$**

I tried to prove that the generators need to have order two, but I wasn’t able to.
I thought that maybe it could be useful two prove that the $s_is_j$’s commute with the each other and then show that these products generate the entire group.

Comment: Can you use [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations)?

Comment: This is simply wrong. The presentation defines an infinite group. I would guess that the intention was to include $s_1^2,s_2^2,s_3^2$ in the defining relators. Any presentation of $({\mathbb Z}/2)^3$ needs at least $6$ relators.

Comment: @Shaun I didn’t know that, but: why not?

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks, I was suspecting that, now I’ll try to prove that!

Comment: The author has a (long) list of errors on her homepage http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/loeh/ggt_book/errata.pdf The one Derek spotted is not among them. Perhaps write her an email.